# Problem adding to solr index using Django-Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm trying to index a model in Solr with django-haystack, but it returns me the following error(when using rebuild_index or update_index) :

```
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: ERROR:unknown field 'django_ct']
```

I followed step by step the "getting started" of Haystack-Search.

I'm using :

- the latest version of Apache Solr (1.4.1)
- the latest version of django-haystack

my search_indexes.py :

```
from haystack.indexes import *
from haystack import site
from models import Entity

class EntityIndex(SearchIndex):
    name = CharField(document=True)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Entity.objects.all()


site.register(Entity, EntityIndex)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure your $SOLR_HOME/conf/schema.xml file contains the 'django_ct' field declaration.  That is a custom field and needs to be added manually along with any other custom fields you are using.

Comment: My schema is generated by `build_solr_schema`, so yeah it's on it.
My schema location is : `~/apache-solr/example/conf/schema.xml`
And i'm running it by `java -jar ~/apache-solr/example/start.jar`
I'm specifying these paths because i'm new to Solr.

Comment: I made a silly mistake, i was querying the apache-solr example not the one installed on Tomcat!

Answer (score 0):

Try using text = CharField(document